# Python Vectorization of a more complex for-loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I would like to vectorize the for loop of this function but all my attempts failed due to broadcasting errors.. I am new to the use of vectorization so I thought someone of you might have more experience and can help me!

The casting errors occurred when I tried to append the `corr_matr` to the global field `self.altes_E`. I thinks its because I want to save the `corr_matr` for each `frequenz` but I do not know how to solve.

```
def phiGCC(self, signal: np.array, TDOA_werte: np.array, __frequency_bins__, alpha: float, altes_E) -> float:

    alle_taus = []

    temp_gcc_ergebnisse = np.zeros((len(TDOA_werte), len(__frequency_bins__)))

    for zaehler, frequenz in enumerate(__frequency_bins__):

        x = np.array([signal[0][zaehler], signal[1][zaehler]])

        y = np.conj(x)
        y = y.T

        E = np.outer(x,y)
        E = x[:,None]*y

        if(self.iterator == 1):
            corr_matr = E
        else:
            corr_matr = alpha * self.altes_E[zaehler] + (1 - alpha) * E
        self.altes_E[zaehler] = corr_matr

        max_tau = 0
        Rxx12 = corr_matr[0,1]

        temp_gcc_ergebnisse[:,zaehler] = (Rxx12/abs(Rxx12) * np.exp(-2j * np.pi * TDOA_werte * frequenz)).real

        i = np.argmax(temp_gcc_ergebnisse[:,zaehler])
        max_tau = TDOA_werte[i]

        alle_taus.append(max_tau)


    tau_func = np.mean(temp_gcc_ergebnisse, axis=1)
    maximaler_wert = np.argmax(tau_func)
    return alle_taus[maximaler_wert]
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example, supply input, maybe random numbers, use general variable names, remove complex equations. Remove everything that is not related to the problem.

Comment: In `signal` is a (2,n) array, then `x=signal[:, zaehler]` should work.  Or take it out of the loop and use `x=signal.copy()` (may not even need the copy, if you aren't changing `x` values).

Comment: Hi sorry I cannot provide data because there are to few characters within the answer box. But `signal` has a shape of (2, 257) `TDOA_werte` has a shape of (200, ) `__frequency_bins__` has a shape of (257, ), `altes_E` or `self.altes_E` has a shape of (257, 2, 2) and is required to store the `corr_matr` which depends on the `frequenz` values. `alpha` is a float number between 0 and 1 . This function is already working and most of it is related to the problem because it depends on the variables the for loop is iterating through.